# Evitar error en Java Netbeans: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, formularios, netbeans

> Buenas, tengo el siguiente formulario en NetBeans
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla que aparece al costado lleva tiene como nombre de variable `tabla_cliente`

Los botones "Editar" `btneditarcliente` y "Eliminar" `btneliminarcliente` me sirven para editar o eliminar los registros de las tablas (o sea las filas enteras)

El caso es que para editar o eliminar un registro primero tengo que seleccionarlo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que si presiono los botones editar o eliminar antes de seleccionar un registro, me sale el sgte. error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta es, cómo puedo hacer que si presiono los botones editar o eliminar antes de seleccionar un registro, no me salga un error, sino que el sistema me avise que primero debo seleccionar un registro??

Por si les sirve, ésta es la interfaz del botón editar:

```
private void btneditarclienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    btnguardarcliente.setEnabled(true);
    btneliminarcliente.setEnabled(false);
    btnnuevocliente.setEnabled(false);
    txtdnicliente.setEnabled(true);
    txtnombrecliente.setEnabled(true);
    txtdircliente.setEnabled(true);
    modificar=true;
    int fila=tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow();   
    txtdnicliente.setText(tabla_cliente.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
    txtnombrecliente.setText(tabla_cliente.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());
    txtdircliente.setText(tabla_cliente.getValueAt(fila, 2).toString());
}
```

Comment: Sería importante agregar el código para saber que causa el problema,. revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Ahora he añadido más detalles..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El metodo `getSelectedRow()` devuelve -1 si no hay fila seleccionada, al intentar obtener el valor en el `getValueAt` le esta metiendo como numero de fila el -1 que esta fuera del índice de cualquier array y lanza la excepción. Pon un `if` para controlar que, si `fila > 0` ejecute las lineas del `getValueAt`. En el mismo `else` podrías poner un `JOptionPane` para mostrar un mensaje de error.

```
private void btneditarclienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        btnguardarcliente.setEnabled(true);
        btneliminarcliente.setEnabled(false);
        btnnuevocliente.setEnabled(false);
        txtdnicliente.setEnabled(true);
        txtnombrecliente.setEnabled(true);
        txtdircliente.setEnabled(true);
        modificar=true;
        int fila=tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow();  
        if(fila>0) {
            txtdnicliente.setText(tabla_cliente.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
            txtnombrecliente.setText(tabla_cliente.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());
            txtdircliente.setText(tabla_cliente.getValueAt(fila, 2).toString());
        }else{
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "mensaje");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Supongo que no tienes el código dentro de un `try catch`
El `try` sirve para decirle al código "a ver, intenta hacer esto",
y el `catch` es para decirle "ah, okey. no sirvió eso, entonces haz esto".

No se como este tu codigo, pero puedes hacer algo así:

```
        try {

            //Codigo a realizar, en este caso sería comprobar si hay algo seleccionado

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { //aqui "cachamos" el error
            //aqui podemos imprimir el error
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            //Aqui nosotros ponemos el mensaje.
            System.out.println("Error, tienes que seleccionar un usuario");
        }
```

Espero que eso te ayude!

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], debemos brindar una opción para solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta., saludos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la observación. Según yo estoy brindando una opción para que se resuelva el problema, que sería metiendo el código dentro de un Try-Catch. pero si hay algún problema con mi respuesta, con gusto la edito para que sea mejor.

Comment: Try-Catch solo sirve para "atrapar" el error, pero en realidad no resuelve el problema. No necesita imprimir el error ahí ya que es el mismo que muestra en su pregunta, el OP debería agregar su código para conocer que esta realizando.

Comment: El OP pidió una manera de que el sistema le avise si no tiene un usuario seleccionado, y eso se puede hacer en el catch. en lugar de poner un `System.out.println("Error"); `, se podría hacer otra cosa, como mostrar una ventana. Yo puse eso como ejemplo. Pero tienes razón, falta el código para hacer algo más concreto.

Comment: He añadido más detalles a mi código, por si les pueda servir..